# How to save a string without explicit escaping?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make my Django based API return an HTML snippet as a string. I am retrieving the HTML snippet through a BeautifulSoup bs4 element. To convert it into a string, I am simply using the `str()` operation as follows:

```py
 test['key'] = str(bs4_element)
```

When I retrieve this value from an API call, I get the HTML code, however, with backslash characters inserted throughout to escape special characters, somewhat like this:

```
"key": "<div class=\"hackdown\"><style id=\"MathJax_SVG_styles\">...
```

I want to render this retrieved HTML in a browser, however, the introduced backslash characters are not letting me do the same.

How do I convert the bs4 element such that the above is prevented?

Comment: how do you render it ? It should skip \ when you use this string - see `print( "<div class=\"hackdown\">")` gives normal string `<div class="hackdown">`

Comment: BTW: if you render string HTML in `Django` (or `Flask`) then you may have to use option `safe` because `Django` (`Flask`) for security reason may add slashes, so it may not be problem with `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: see Django doc: [autoescape / safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/)

Comment: @furas I am not really rendering it myself. My goal is to design an API such that anyone who calls it gets a well formed HTML snippet which they can directly insert as HTML in their pages. In the current form, the response cannot be used directly without pre-processing.

Comment: I think you have problem in different place because `BS` gives correct HTML. Problem can be only if original HTML has double  \\ - then `BS` will return also \\ and you may see it. But single \ means nothing - \" is used only if you try to put in code string with `"` inside `" "` but Python will skip this information when you try to use this string. BTW: you should check if `print( '\\' in  test['key'])` gives `True` or `Flase`. If you get `False` then you don't have \ in this moment and maybe different function add this \ - ie. maybe when Django sends it to client then it add it

Comment: BTW: if your API sends data in JSON format then module `json` adds \ to every `"` to cerate correct JSON data - because JSON uses `"` as beginning and end of string in data. But normally clients use module `json` to convert string back to Python's dictionary and it automatically removes this \ from strings. And this way clients normally don't have problem with \ in strings. See" convert data to JSON `print(json.dumps('<"text">'))` and convert JSON back to data `print(json.loads(json.dumps('<"text">')))`